# My modifier keys on my MacBook Pro have stopped working as expected, how can I fix them?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

First I'll highlight I've been using this MacBook for about 3 months, it's my first Mac in 7 years, in between I've been using Thinkpads.

This sounds really odd, but the other day I powered up my MacBook pro and my modifier keys had stopped working as expected.

If I'm in Microsoft Office, say Excel, then `ctrl-c` and `ctrl-v` work as expected but in other applications commands like `cmd-c` and `cmd-v` don't.
The commands for taking a screenshot don't work.
The commands for navigating between windows and applications (`cmd-tab` and `cmd-tilde`) don't work.
In my IDE, none of the commands that involved navigating (`optn-cmd-arrow keys`) work,
copy/paste doesn't work, nothing that involves a modifier and a function keys works.
I am at a complete loss as to why this is the case.
As best I can tell everything looks OK in the configuration, but I haven't used Mac in a while so I'm not sure.

I have not made any changes beyond installing an ANSI keyboard (the MacBook itself has a Nordic layout) but this has been fine for months.
How can I troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: How did you "install" an ANSI keyboard? First test, System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard; ☑︎Show Keyboard & Emoji viewers in menu bar, then open the keyboard viewer. Make sure the keypresses are recognised.

Comment: I plugged it in, the mac said it was "installing", and I added an ansi layout. I can switch between that and the nordic default. It worked fine for the last few months, just stopped this week. I'll try your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It was a keyboard setting, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a function of my Varmilo M108 keyboard. The Windows key was disabled, which you can do by pressing `fn` + `Windows` key. You re-enable it by pressing the same keys again.
I'd bet it was my cat walking across the keyboard that did it when I wasn't in the room.
The `Windows` key doubles as the `CMD` key on mac.